# How to execute a T-SQL script with temp tables and showing the table on C# MVC App

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

For example, I have a script that contains

```
insert into #temp from TABLES
insert into #temp1 from #temp
select * from #temp
```

I already have a C# MVC application. I just want to be able to execute the script above to display the #temp table on my front-end. I have seen the function `ExecuteNonQuery()`, however, it only shows the rows affected. Is there anyone that can point me a guide to solve this issue?

EDIT: I just want to run the script above and obtain the results, i don't want to rewrite the script in a framework.

Comment: @GuruprakashC could you show me a reference?

Comment: Try this SELECT * INTO #temp FROM TABLES; SELECT  * FROM tempdb..#temp

Comment: If you need results, don't use `ExecuteNonQuery`, which, as the name implies, is not intended to be used with queries. Use `ExecuteReader` and/or an ORM like Dapper or Entity Framework.

Comment: do yourself a favor and use EF (Entity Framework) for these kind of tasks. That's what it's there for. Linq will set you free.

Comment: @LongChalk not every SQL operation requires EF. This case looks like a simple case and no need of EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for ExecuteNonQuery:

```
private void ExecuteNonQuery(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8)

And you can call your inserts like this: `ExecuteNonQuery("insert into #temp from TABLES", connectionString);`

For reading you can use `ExecuteReader` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8)) But if your table has many columns, this can be tedious to display all the columns. I prefer to use micro ORM (or data mapper otherwise) like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) - it is easy to use, minimum set up and with plenty of documentation.

Some people advise to use Entity Framework, but for this case it looks like will be an overkill. Also it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Actually, this is just a case for 3 lines of code. But, i am planning to use this idea to execute 100-1000 lines of SQL code. Is your method still good? Or is the entity framework a better solution

Comment: If you have a lot of hand-crafted SQL, EF will be an overkill. `ExecuteNonQuery` is a standard way to run any kind of SQL when working with SQL Server from C#. Does not matter if it is a 3-lines or 1000. You might want to look into transactions around all your stuff and get more familiar with Dapper, otherwise I wouldn't recomment EF based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read data from temporary table so use the ExecuteReader() and refer the following code.

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
       var myString = rdr.GetString(0); //The 0 stands for "the 0'th column", so the 
       first column of the result.
       // Do somthing with this rows string, for example to put them in to a list
       listDeclaredElsewhere.Add(myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i just want to run a script?

Answer (score 0):

For select you have can use DataSet object and using DataAdapter fill data to DataSet

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(commandObject);
da.fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(commandObject);
da.fill(ds);
```

yes, that would work as well. but be aware that you are working with a DataSet (not DataTable on purpose?), and both DataSet and it's matching DataTable(s) are all dynamic objects without type safety (i.e. you are working with `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2] as string;` ).
good luck with the runtime exceptions.